# IIS Intermittent Change of Rewrite Settings

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, iis, http-status-code-404

I have my application build based on CodeIgniter, and the application running on IIS7.5 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

We also have 4 separate databases, one of each operating state which runs on the same server. (i know probably not best practice, but its what i have been given to work with. i was not original designer).

So my folder structure goes like this, and is duplicated for each state.

```
wwwroot/
  |
  |-{STATE}/
  |----|index.php //CI Index.php
  |-{STATE}/
  |----|index.php //CI Index.php
```

The state folders are windows directories with names written in Capitals.

each folder has a web.config file to rewrite uri requests to index.php

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true" />

        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="RuleRemoveIndex" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

now here is where i am confused.

The application some times works, and sometimes does not work depending on weather the state component (https://{SUB}.{DOMAIN}:{PORT}/{STATE}/{URI}) is written in capitals or not.

When i originally put it up on the server, i tested it with lower case letters {state} and everything worked fine. I came back the next day, and found that using the lower case letters would give me a CodeIgniter 404 error. But if i used Capital letters {STATE} it would work find. and then it would change around again later.

after doing some url rewite testing using same principles here: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module 
but changed to php, i noticed that

I also did some URL REWRITE testing to see what the outcomes of the URL Rewrites were, based on the aspx version here: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module 
but changed to php. What i found was that $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] was retaining the first way in which the the {STATE} was being type (Capital or lower case). My temporary fix is simply what i am sure is bad practice, 
I added this script to the start of my index.php file

```
$_script_name = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$_script_name_array = explode('/', $_script_name);
$_script_name_array[1] = strtolower($_script_name_array[1]);
$_script_name = implode('/', $_script_name_array);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']=$_script_name;
```

which has half fixed the issue, it basically forces the use of states in lower case. 
It would be nice if a solution could be found so that it doesn't matter if the {state} is written in capitals or not.

I was hoping someone on here might have some idea's.

Comment: I have the same issue with a simple php script using URL rewriting. I'm adding a bounty because I really would like to know how to fix it too...

Comment: Will this help you? https://www.simonholywell.com/post/2012/11/force-lowercase-urls-rewrite-php.html

Comment: Not so much, since we're using IIS, and this article is about Apache, and it only offers an alternate version of Lars' workaround. Thanks for offering though

Answer (score 0):

IIS Rewrite would be handy in this case

Add the following code to your web.config file located in the root of your web folder.

```
<rule name="LowerCaseRule" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
<action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
</rule>
```

Here [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference) you can find more details on it.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it tomorrow at work and get back to you

Comment: We already tried this, and it's only a workaround. Plus, it doesn't work as well as the PHP script @Lars offered.

Comment: @3rgo Its not a work around its  "URL Rewrite Module" authentic way to rewrite the URLs.  Please refer this link: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: Yes, I know, but this is still not the way to fix IIS not having the same behaviour every time

Comment: Then I'll suggest its better move to Apache.

Comment: If only it were that easy... We instead had to move to IIS from Apache (client technical constraint)...